# Selecting installed certificates in a modal window

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in javascript to show a modal window to users and allow them to select one certificate.
Certificates are available in certmgr.msc (Windows Certificates).
Just like the picture below.
[image]

Comment: No. Not all browsers do use Windows Certificates (or even run on Windows at all). What do you want that for?

Comment: I want my user select one certificate and then use that certificate for encryption.

Comment: I don't think you can trigger the browser's certificate selection process from javascript - at least not without additional privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser, but not your *javascript*, that decides when to show *Select certificate* window. So, the question is how to trigger an event: configure **SSL Client Certificate authentication** on your **web-server**, while TLS-handshake the web-server will send a parameter asking a client's certificate.